# Clarification on Difference Formula for nodes near boundary

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-difference-methods

[image]

The above is an extract from my precis on numerical solutions to PDE, finite difference method giving explanation for difference formula  for nodes near boundary when step length is not equal (equation (25)). At the side is problem E3(d) with answer as given in the precis. When I tried to solve it, I got

$a_0=-54\;\;a_1=24\;\;a_2=a_4=9\;\;a_3=12$. Further, I get correct equations as given in the solution for points 1 and 3 using:

at 1:$\;\;$ h$^2$G($\frac{2}{3}$,$\frac{2}{3}$)=$\frac{5}{27}$ = -4u$_1$+u$_2$+u$_3$

at 3:$\;\;$ h$^2$G($\frac{2}{3}$,$\frac{4}{3}$)=$\frac{44}{27}$ = u$_1$-4u$_3$+u$_4$

However, at 2 and 4 I get

12u$_1$-54u$_2$+9u$_4$ = $\frac{-479}{27}$ $\;\;$and

9u$_2$+12u$_3$-54u$_4$ = $\frac{-17}{27}$$\;\;$ only if LHS in equation (25) is multiplied by h$^2$. So is there a printing mistake in LHS of equation (25) where h$^2$ has been missed out, or has the solution at points 2 and 4 been mistakenly calculated by multiplying LHS of equation (25) by h$^2$?

Would be grateful for guidance and clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eq.(25) is correct.

In the textbook there is evidently a mistake in the Solution E3 as you write. If one looks at coefficients of Eqs. (1,3), the coefficient for $u_i$ should be $a_0=-36$, but it is only $-4$, which means that the Eqs. (1,3) were divided by $9$. However in Eqs. (2,4) the coefficient for $u_i$ should be $a_0=-54$ and it is really $-54$, i.e. they are undivided. All right hand sides however contain terms divided by $27$. I think that they forgot to divide left hand sides of Eqs. (2,4) by $9$.

By the way the derivation of Eq.25 is elegant, I keep it in mind ;-).

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for clearing my doubt. Is it possible to share a link for derivation of equation 25? My precis just states it wihout derivation. The derivation in my preics is only for coefficients a

Comment: I mean the derivation, which is already in your screenshot. Your take the Taylor series at all 4 points and the coefficients of all terms between the left and the right hand side must coincide. Immediately you get Eqs. (26-30). Eq.(25) is actually like a definition (what you want to be valid) and you choose coefficients so that Eq. (25) is true.

Comment: Oh OK thanks.I didnt know 25 was definition, and so proof is not required for that. Yes equations 26-30 derivation is understood.

Comment: Definition in the sense that you write down what you wish to be valid and then you only check coefficients to force this validity.